# centrifugal pump vibration data predictive model

Tags: predictive-modeling

I am a beginner in data analysis. I have vibration data of 5 centrifugal pumps in .csv format and I want to make a model which predict the error using vibration data. Can anyone guide me, how to start and which algorithm will be helpful to detect the error? Thanks in advance for your help and suggestions.